# SQL Using SSL to encrypt a single connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, ssl

I want to force all external connections to be encrypted using SSL, essentially I want to encrypt only one of the network interfaces.

This article comes about as close to my answer as I can get:
http://basitaalishan.com/2012/07/16/encrypting-connections-to-sql-server/

However, it seems to me that either all connections are forced to use encryption or all connections may be able to not use encryption at all. I want all external connections to be encrypted (no choice) and all internal connections (behind the firewall) to not be encrypted.

I need to encrypt both SQL 2005 and 2008R2. Both are running on Windows 2008 Std

Can this be done at all?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: Ah yes, I realised after posting the question that I was missing some essential information. I need to encrypt both SQL 2005 and 2008R2. Both are running on Windows 2008 Std.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SSL wrapper/proxy like [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html), then set the firewall to allow external connections only to the port where said SSL wrapper runs.

Comment: I'll look into this. I use pfSense as my primary firewall and I think it may be able to do the trick.

Comment: Having wrestled with Stunnel for the better part of a day it looks like it simply doesn't work. Either that or it doesn't work on the current version of pfSense. Unfortunately I can't find another SSL wrapper that works with pfSense.

Comment: stunnel does not need to run on the firewall, it can run on the DB server (there seems to be a windows version) or actually any other machine in the same network.